# Puppeteer is blocked by the site https://nationsglory.fr/servers when it redirects to the requested page. How to pass this redirect?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Thank you to everyone who will look into my problem.
I was always able to scrape easily with puppetter but not on this page https://nationsglory.fr/servers.
The latest version of puppeteer prevents me from going on the page, I get stuck at the redirection.
This is why I run my script under the version:

```
         "puppeteer": "7.0.1",
         "puppeteer-extra": "3.1.16",
         "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "2.7.4"
```

With these versions, I manage from time to time to pass and I can scrape the data of this site.
But I wish it would work all the time and I don't know how to make it happen.
Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const { log } = require("npm-colorlog");
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

let countryInfos = "";
//true for hidden Chromium
//ancian ip, dos is useless
puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    timeout: 10 * 60 * 1000,
    args: [
        "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disabe-infobars",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
        "--window-position=0,0",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list"
    ],

}).then(async browser => {
    console.log('✷ Running browser..')
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    //    await page.setViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 })

    await page.goto('https://nationsglory.fr/server/yellow/countries')
// the code gets stuck here because the redirection fails and the page refreshes in a loop 
    
await page.waitForTimeout(500);
    await page
        .waitForSelector('.lead', { timeout: 10 * 60 * 1000 })
        .then(() => console.log('load page!'));
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'botTester.png' });
    //i screen for show if i pass


    const hrefs = await page.$$eval("tr > td > a", (list) => list.map((elm) => elm.href));
    const links = [];

    hrefs.forEach(hf => {
        if (hf.startsWith('https://nationsglory.fr/country/yellow/') == true) {
            links.push(hf)
        }
    });
    const linkLength = links.length / 2;
    for (let i = 0; i < linkLength; i++) {
        let pay = links[i].substring(37, links[i].length)

        await page.goto(links[i])
        await page
            .waitForSelector('.section-title', { timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000 })
            .then(() => console.log('load country'));
        await page.waitForTimeout(500);
        page.waitForSelector('#bodymembers>tr>.pl-4 > a > div');

        const claims = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".mb-2"), element => element.textContent));
        const powers = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".col-md-3 > .mb-2"), element => element.textContent));
        const members = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(" >tr>.pl-4 > a > div"), element => element.textContent));


        let level = claims[2];
        let power = powers[1].split("/");
        let claim = claims[4];
        power = parseInt(power[0], 10)
        claim = parseInt(claim, 10)

        countryInfos += "n°" + i + pay + " → ♝ level: " + level + " → ♚ power: " + power + " → ♛ claim: " + claim + "\n" + "→ ♟Members: " + members ";

    }
    const fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile('countryInfos.txt', countryInfos, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('File created !');
    });
    await browser.close();
    console.log("✨All done, check the console✨");
})
```

If you have any questions do not hesitate.
Thank you all for your help !